# Spring client SOAP with Builder pattern

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot, soap

I start on Spring and I want to use a WebServiceTemplateBuilder (equivalent to a RestTemplateBuilder for REST) but I can not find on the Web there an existing SOAP client implementation with WebServiceTemplate using the Builder patterns?

Thank you!

Comment: I want to do with the SOAP client (org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate) what you can do with the REST client (org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder)

Comment: RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder()        
 .setConnectTimeout(apiClientConfigProperties.getTimeout().getConnect())
         .setReadTimeout(apiClientConfigProperties.getTimeout().getRead())
         .additionalMessageConverters(httpJsonMessageConverter)
        
 .uriTemplateHandler(uriTemplateHandler()).errorHandler(errorHandler).build();